# How to connect postgresql container to django container?

Tags: vagrant, docker

I have the 2 containers mentioned running with *Vagrant* how do I connect my Django app from one container to Postgresql on the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea:

**TL;DR:** [Read this to know how to link containers](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/postgres/)

I should be able to easily connect containers when they are running with a project already setup/coded, either in the host machine or a VM.

---

I have read a bit here and there. Found out how to install everything I need in a container, but that would not be isolating db setup from app. These are the conclusions I've drawn so far:

1. Docker's use cases are to run/test projects in an isolated manner, the process of programming and setting up the project (in my case, a Django app) is done in a Vagrant VM or on the host machine. Then after a certain point in development, I'd run the project in a container to test the behavior. So the premise that I'd be developing in a Docker, while possible, is not part of their philosophy.
2. Docker's purpose is, after testing/development, to deploy in containers using the same or better setup used to test the project.